# How to get the finalY of lastAutoTable in jspdf-autoTable

Tags: angular, jspdf, html-to-pdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using angular 9.I have a requirement to convert a html table with some content above and below the table into pdf. I am using jspdf-autotable.I followed the examples in the link https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/examples/examples.js and I am able to write a heading and then generate the table.The problem is when I need to add some text lines below the table.

My code is as below.

```
generatePdf(){
const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(18)
doc.text('ATTENDANCE REPORT FOR DEPOT - '+this.depotId, 14, 22);
autoTable(doc, { html: '#report-per-depot',startY: 30, });
doc.text(" ", 14, doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 10)
doc.save('AttandancePerDepot.pdf');

}
```

The error I get is

```
Property 'lastAutoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'.
```

I tried to import lastAutoTable as, import lastAutoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';
I doesnt show any error,but I am not sure how to get the finalY from it.

```
  lastAutoTable(doc,{});
```

The above doesnt show error but its return type is void.So this is where I am stuck.
How do I get the finalY position in angular 9 or 10?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're getting this error because Typescript is a strongly Typed language & **lastAutoTable** is not defined in the index.d.ts file (under jsPdf node module).

Below is a small hack to get around this error & get finalY value.

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
    
let finalY = (doc as any).lastAutoTable.finalY;
```

This worked for me in my Angular 10 project

Comment: great that u can add (object as any) in typescript

Answer (score 2):

In angular 12 (Typescript)

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable'
```

Then in the method

```
    crearPDF() {

    const doc =  new jsPDF();
    let finalY = 0;

    for (const key in this.entradasIndentificaciones) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.entradasIndentificaciones, key)) {
        const element = this.entradasIndentificaciones[key];
        doc.text(element, 30, finalY + 10);
        autoTable(doc, { html: '#tableOn-' + key });
        finalY = (doc as any).lastAutoTable.finalY;

      }
    }
    console.debug("Guardando");
    doc.save("Report_.pdf");
  }
```

respects